# Is it ok to use an enamelled Dutch oven on an electric stove top with the older ring burners?

Tags: electric-stoves, dutch-oven

I bought my first enameled Dutch oven and I've been trying to do some research on whether or not I can use it on the older electric ring burner stove tops without it cracking on me. 
[image]

If anyone could give advice it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it enameled on the OUTSIDE of the bottom? My rather ancient Le Cru... has a large hole in the enamel job (from the factory) corresponding to the bottom exterior of the pot, which just happens to be the part that contacts the burner. Probably also where the pot sat while the enamel was being baked on in the first place. It has held up to that type of burner just fine. I don't use it for frying/searing (I use a plain cast iron frying pan for that) but it cooks on the stovetop (or in the oven) just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Oh sure, you can use an enameled Dutch oven on that type of stove. That type of burner (hob) is still the most common in the US; I haven't had anything *but* that type (in my home) in my adult life. An enameled cast iron Dutch oven will discolor when used on any stove, but it wont crack unless allowed to burn "dry" or if the pan was defective to begin with.